# Query MongoDB to display only one section of data

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, nosql

I have created a MongoDB database and have it hooked up to a MEAN stack web application I have created. I have it able to display the most recent set of data put into it rather than all of the data but now I want to take that down to display only 1 section of that data, as there are currently 50 different sections.

I am using post.find and then sorting the data to show only the most recent record from the DB but I am struggling to break it down to show only one part of that data. Current data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TDJG.jpg.
As you can see the data is grouped by "S0" and then data follows, then there is "S1" etc... In essence what I want is for just "S0" to be displayed when queried.

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Post.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1)
    .then(function (posts) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        status: 200,
        data: posts,
        message: 'Success'
      })
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 400,
        message: err.message
      });
    });
}
```

I believe I need to add to the find query but I am not sure how to specify that I would only like to see "S0" rather than S0-S49.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return only specific fields from query you should use `Project Fields`:

```
Post.find({}, {"s0": 1}).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1)
```

Here is the docs [Project Fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)